# Can I slow down the scrolling speed of ion-datetime components?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, datetimepicker

Users using ionic3.
The scrolling speed of ion-datetime is too fast for me.
So I want to reduce the scroll sensitivity.

I've manipulated the “animation-duration” property.
I did not get the result I wanted.

For current ion-datetime components:
If you scroll from position 10 to v-speed, you move up to 20

But I'd like to make sure it only moves up to 15 when I scroll at the same v-speed.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omFLd.jpg)

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have the same issue.  Ionic 4 though.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to resolve this?

Comment: looking for the same answer ?
on ios, it's scrolling very fast.